# Method in C# to return the immediate text character of a given character

Tags: c#, .net, function, character

How can I implement a function in c# that return the immediate text character of a given text character. The characters should be in alphabetic order.
Example: given the character "C" the method should return the character "D".

Comment: What should it return when you pass `z` ;)

Comment: I already have a function that use a fixed array that contains all the letters. But I think this is not the better solution for the problem.

Comment: when we pass z it suppose return "aa". Passing "aa" retunr "ab" ...

Comment: Does it matter if the characters are upper or lower case?  Also what if the string contains non-alpha characters?

Comment: Yes it matter @juharr. If I give "a" it must return 'b', if I give "A" it must return 'B'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution:

```
public static string GetNextLetter(string letter = null)
{
     if (IsStringNullOrEmpty(letter))
         return "A";

     char lastLetter = letter.Last();

     if (lastLetter.ToString() == "Z")
         return GetNextLetter(RemoveLastCharacter(letter)) + "A";
     else
         return RemoveLastCharacter(letter) + (char)(lastLetter + 1);
    }
```

Any better solutions are welcome.

Comment: This doesn't seem to handle lower case "z".  Also you can just compare `lastLetter` without the `ToString` like `lastLetter == 'Z'`.  Also not sure what `RemoveLastCharacter` is, but `letter.Remove(letter.Length - 1);` will return the string with the last character removed.

Comment: The RemoveLastCharacter function does exactly the same as { letter.Remove(letter.Length - 1) }. As I need only upper letters, I will use the str.ToUpper() function to guarantee that I always get a result with upper letters.

Answer (score 5):

```
char c = 'C';
char i = (char)(c + 1);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i);
```

It will output 'D' to the Debug Output window.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method that should do what you want.  There is no checking for non-alpha characters though.

```
public static string ToNextAlpha(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("str");
        // Or you can just return "a";
    }

    var end = new StringBuilder();
    for (int index = str.Length - 1; index >= 0; index--)
    {
        char c = str[index];
        bool isZed = c == 'z' || c == 'Z';
        c = (char)(isZed ? c - 25 : c + 1);
        end.Insert(0, c);
        if (!isZed)
        {
            return str.Substring(0, index) + end;
        }
    }

    return "a" + end;
}
```

Note: This will turn "zz" into "aaa" and "ZZ" into "aAA".  If you want to prepend an upper case "A" just change the last line with whatever logic you need.

Comment: Your function works just fine. Maybe my function is more elegant because off being recursive.